# Is there a way to fix Ambari Web 2.7.1.0.0 build issue?

Tags: maven, hadoop, ambari

## Issue

I am currently setting an Ambari cluster and getting stuck at the ambari-web build stage

## Environment

```
[root@hdp ambari-web]# node -v
v10.24.0
[root@hdp ambari-web]# yarn -v
1.22.5
[root@hdp ambari-web]# npm -v
6.14.11
[root@hdp ambari-web]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
[root@hdp ambari-web]#
```

## Outputs

```
[root@hdp apache-ambari-2.7.1-src]# mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.1.0.0 -DbuildNumber=90430db08a5f543a97d97918cf5f711f2786ad8a -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from maven2-repository.dev.java.net: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-external/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from maven2-glassfish-repository.dev.java.net: http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-external/maven-metadata.xml

.....  << omit the middle outputs


[INFO] --------------------< org.apache.ambari:ambari-web >--------------------
[INFO] Building Ambari Web 2.7.1.0.0                                     [3/42]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src/ambari-web (includes = [**/*.pyc], excludes = [])
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (clean-rmdir) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (clean-mkdir) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:regex-property (parse-package-version) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:regex-property (parse-package-release) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:parse-version (parse-version) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:regex-property (regex-property) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO] Node v4.5.0 is already installed.
[INFO] Yarn 0.23.2 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:yarn (yarn install) @ ambari-web ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn install --ignore-engines --pure-lockfile' in /home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src/ambari-web
[INFO] yarn install v0.23.2
[ERROR] warning Ambari@2.4.0: No license field
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[INFO] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[INFO] info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src/ambari-web/yarn-error.log".
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ember-radio-button/-/ember-radio-button-0.1.2.tgz: ETIMEDOUT".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Ambari Main 2.7.1.0.0 .............................. SUCCESS [  2.695 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM 2.7.1.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.251 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web 2.7.1.0.0 ............................... FAILURE [04:16 min]
[INFO] Ambari Views 2.7.1.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Admin View 2.7.1.0.0 ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-utility 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-metrics 2.7.1.0.0 ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common 2.7.1.0.0 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink 2.7.1.0.0 ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink 2.7.1.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink 2.7.1.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink 2.7.1.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy) 2.7.1.0.0 ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector 2.7.1.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor 2.7.1.0.0 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Grafana 2.1.0.0.0 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Host Aggregator 2.7.1.0.0 ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly 2.7.1.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Service Advisor 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server 2.7.1.0.0 ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Functional Tests 2.7.1.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent 2.7.1.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-logsearch 2.7.1.0.0 ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Appender 2.7.1.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Api 2.7.1.0.0 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config JSON 2.7.1.0.0 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Solr 2.7.1.0.0 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Zookeeper 2.7.1.0.0 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Local 2.7.1.0.0 ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Plugin Api 2.7.1.0.0 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Container Registry 2.7.1.0.0 SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder 2.7.1.0.0 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Web 2.7.1.0.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Server 2.7.1.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Assembly 2.7.1.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Integration Test 2.7.1.0.0 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-infra 2.7.1.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Client 2.7.1.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Plugin 2.7.1.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager 2.7.1.0.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Assembly 2.7.1.0.0 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager Integration Tests 2.7.1.0.0 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-27T01:10:38-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:yarn (yarn install) on project ambari-web: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --ignore-engines --pure-lockfile' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ambari-web
```

I am trying to run "yarn install --ignore-engines --pure-lockfile --network-timeout 100000" under "/home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src/ambari-web" . But I got stuck on fetching packages

```
[root@hdp ambari-web]# pwd
/home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src/ambari-web
[root@hdp ambari-web]# cd ..
[root@hdp apache-ambari-2.7.1-src]# pwd
/home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src
[root@hdp apache-ambari-2.7.1-src]# ls
ambari-admin   ambari-funtest    ambari-metrics  ambari-serviceadvisor  ambari-web   docs         logo.png    pom.xml             version
ambari-agent   ambari-infra      ambari-project  ambari-utility         contrib      KEYS         NOTICE.txt  start-build-env.sh
ambari-common  ambari-logsearch  ambari-server   ambari-views           dev-support  LICENSE.txt  pass.txt    target
[root@hdp apache-ambari-2.7.1-src]# cd ambari-web/
[root@hdp ambari-web]# ls
api-docs                           gzip-content.ps1  pom.xml                 set-ambari-version.sh          toggle-experimental.cmd  yarn.lock
app                                gzip-content.sh   public                  set-default-stack-version.cmd  toggle-experimental.ps1
brunch-config.js                   karma.conf.js     public-static           set-default-stack-version.ps1  toggle-experimental.sh
copy-pluggable-stack-resources.sh  node              set-ambari-version.cmd  set-default-stack-version.sh   vendor
gzip-content.cmd                   package.json      set-ambari-version.ps1  test                           yarn-error.log
[root@hdp ambari-web]# pwd
/home/apache-ambari-2.7.1-src/ambari-web
[root@hdp ambari-web]#

[root@hdp ambari-web]# yarn install --ignore-engines --pure-lockfile --network-timeout 100000
yarn install v1.22.5
warning package.json: No license field
warning Ambari@2.4.0: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
^C
```

#Next step#

Need help how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Any one could help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you won't be able to do that.
Because ambari will need to download the repo from hortonwork.
Eventually it will still fail, since there is no public for the hortonwork from 31/01/2021.

Comment: How does that work exactly? Go to an open source project, contribute, the lock it behind a paywall? How it it possible that open source is un-buildable with access to now-private resources?

Comment: That is result of cloudera merge hortonworks. If hortonwork is free, who buy clodera?